# I'm having trouble getting Bootstrap mobile collapse to work

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm new to bootstrap and working with navbar. I'd like logos in left, right middle. I've tried the below code but it does not work, any suggestions?

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>    
        </div>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
              <li><a href="#">Left</a></li>
              <li><a href="#about">Left</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#about">Right</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Right</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
   </nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recreated a navbar for you to use with brand logo in the center.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

    </div>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}
```

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/Gothburz/pen/PPdBNv/)

Comment: still not expanded. but if i remove position : absolute; line. its work. i have no idea.

Comment: its seems the navbar toogle is overlaping with navbar brand, here the code .navbar-toggle{
z-index: 10;
}

Comment: glad you figured that out! I updated the pen as well.